How to understand cudaMemAdviseSetPreferredLocation and cudaMemAdviseSetAccessedBy?
I have misunderstanding about cudaMemAdviseSetPreferredLocation and cudaMemAdviseSetAccessedBy when using cudaMallocManaged()?
Making some tests.
// test 1
cudaMallocManaged((void**)&dev, size *sizeof(float));
cudaMemAdvise(dev, size * sizeof(float), cudaMemAdviseSetPreferredLocation, cudaCpuDeviceId);
initialData(dev, size); // init in cpu
TestKernel<<<grid, block>>>(dev, size);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
// test 2
cudaMallocManaged((void**)&dev, size *sizeof(float));
cudaMemAdvise(dev, size * sizeof(float), cudaMemAdviseSetPreferredLocation, 0);
initialData(dev, size); // init in cpu
TestKernel<<<grid, block>>>(dev, size);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

From the Nsight Systems, test 2 has Host-to-Device Migration while test 1 has no Migration.
So how do cudaMemAdviseSetPreferredLocation and cudaMemAdviseSetAccessedBy map their page?

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre]

The results seem logical to me. Please describe in detail why you think the results should be different.
